# Bash script/command to bulk remove "@2x" from filename (retina image -> normal)

Tags: bash, rename, bulk, mv

How do I rename a bulk of files in a bash command or script, to remove iOS's retina indicator (@2x)?

I've already resized them, but the resize software isn't smart on renaming the output file.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Loops files with '@2x' and renames each one.

${i/AAAA/BBBB} replaces AAAA occurrences in $i with BBBB.

`for i in *@2x.*; do mv $i ${i/@2x/}; done`